# Can I copy PS4 game save data from old user to a new user?

Tags: ps4, final-fantasy-15

I'm trying to transfer my Final Fantasy XV game save data to my new user?

Comment: What issues are you having with this?

Comment: That it says no gave save data when try too copy from old ps 4 user too new ps 4 user

Comment: Can I get my usb and put in my other ps 4 and load the file and overwrite it ?

Answer (score 8):

It appears that it is not possible to transfer saves between users:

> Save Data is account locked so you cannot transfer save data to different accounts. basically to prevent cheating, boosting, etc on the trophies. among other reasons. mainly Piracy

[Source](https://community.playstation.com/content/pdc/us/en_US/pdc-communities/support/games-services.topic.html/transferring_my_ps4-iiVb.html)

You can only transfer them between different PS4 systems, though without the same user on the new system, they cannot be accessed (for the above reason):

> As a backup, you can copy saved data to a USB storage device connected to your PS4™ system. Copy saved data from the USB storage device to another PS4™ system to continue playing a game.
>    For each game, you can select the saved data to copy.
>
> - To use this feature, you need to have signed in to PlayStation™Network at least once.
> - FAT and exFAT formatted USB storage devices are supported.
> - Be sure to fully insert the USB storage device into the USB port. Some devices are not compatible due to shape or design.

[Source](https://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/settings/data_system.html)

Comment: Can I get my usb and put in my other ps 4 and load the file and overwrite it And transfer it back too other ps4 ?