# PS4 game progress data transfer

Tags: ps4, assassins-creed-odyssey

My friend let me start a character in Assassin's Creed Odyssey on his profile to see if I liked it. I did in fact like the game so I ordered it in the mail. Is there a way for me to transfer my progress to my account?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I copy PS4 game save data from old user to a new user?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/353578/can-i-copy-ps4-game-save-data-from-old-user-to-a-new-user)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it does. Thanks mate, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to the forum. I am sorry to be the one breaking it to you, but sadly what you would like to accomplish is not possible. There is no way one could transfer one progress from an account to another, since the progress is saved and tied to the account because of accomplishments and trophies. For more details please see [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/353578/can-i-copy-ps4-game-save-data-from-old-user-to-a-new-user) link.